# Can I look up the text of my foreign cards on my phone in MTG tournaments?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, tournament, mtg-non-english-cards

Hey guys I have a question. I play commander and most of my cards are in foreign language. I use google drive to have a picture of the actual card in English. If I go to a tournament am I allowed to use my phone to check the actual meaning of my cards or no?

Comment: If you have trouble of remembering what your cards do, just play more games with them! After a few long play sessions you'll remember exactly what they are and what do they do.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen It takes quite a while to know all possible interactions though, which the oracle text often matters for - timing, ability type, keyword vs triggered version of the keyword (lifelink/spirit link or hexproof/troll shroud) can all be important differences that you get from the oracle text.

Answer (score 4):

At Regular REL, you might get permission from the Judge, at any higher REL it is forbidden.

> 2.12 Electronic Devices
>
> At Competitive and Professional Rules Enforcement Level
> during drafting, deck construction, and playing of
> matches, players may not use electronic devices capable of taking and
> storing notes, communicating with other people, or accessing the
> internet (except for taking brief personal calls with the opponent's
> permission).
>
> At Regular Rules Enforcement Level, electronic devices are permitted, but players may not use them to access information that contains
> substantial strategic advice or information about an opponent's deck.
> Device use during a match other than brief personal calls must be
> visible to all players. Players wishing to view information privately
> on electronic devices during matches must request permission from a
> judge.

You may however, call a judge to have them provide you with the oracle text (the official version of the text in English) anytime.